# Issues while splitting string using ~

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to split a string using tilde character in C#

My string is: 
"~ALLERGIST~~ALLERGIST345~Add Specialty~ALLERGIST"

My Code as follows:

```cs
    string spl="~ALLERGIST~~ALLERGIST345~Add Specialty~ALLERGIST"
    if (Convert.ToString(spl).Contains("~"))
    {
        string s = Convert.ToString(spl);
        var elements = s.Split(new[] { '~' }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (string items in elements)
        {
            cmb.Items.FindItemByValue(items).Checked = true;
        }
    }
```

After splitting I am getting result.

1. ALLERGIST
2. ALLERGIST345
3. Add Specialty
4. ALLERGIST

Instead the result should be:

1. ~ALLERGIST
2. ~ALLERGIST345
3. Add Specialty
4. ALLERGIST

Comment: but here what you want to trying as I can check the string having only tilde you also want this in result set. You only want to remove tilde from string?

Comment: That's not how `String.Split` works. It removes all Tildas `~` in the resulting string array

Comment: If you hadn't removed those empty entries, you would have found extra entries before the first ~ and between the two.

Comment: Yes, I want to remove tilde, I want to remove separator tilde only, if it is in data then I want it in the string, my first two data have tilde sign

Comment: How would you (or rather the application) distinguish between "separator tilde" and "content tilde"? Why isn't the first word "~ALLERGIST~"?

Comment: What's with all the Convert.ToString() in your code? It's already a string, no need to convert it further

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can handle this via a regex split, which splits on a tilde `~` which is *not* preceded by another tilde.  This splitting logic means that an initial `~` won't cause a split (so `~ALLERGIST` appears as the first output term), and also `~~ALLERGIST345` generates `~ALLERGIST345` as the term.

```
string input = "~ALLERGIST~~ALLERGIST345~Add Specialty~ALLERGIST";
var items = Regex.Split(input, @"(?<=[^~])~");
foreach(var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

This prints:

```
~ALLERGIST
~ALLERGIST345
Add Specialty
ALLERGIST
```